# want to show checked option of checkbox in div order as per selection

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checked

I want to show checked options in div as per order of selection

```
1.  What is the biggest skin concern in India in your practice?
 Number in order of    priority 
 [] Acne                        
 [] Dark circles under eyes             
 [] Dry skin             div is here and it will show list as per selection order
 [] Oily skin                       
 [] Skin color                      
 [] Skin tone evenness              
 [] Wrinkles
```

If somebody select dark skin and then Acne  my div should list down dark skin as first     and after that acne should come

```
input type="checkbox" name="skin_concern[]" id="a2" title="sc" value="Dark    circles under eyes" class="validate[required] radio"
```

Please provide solution on this how i will show this selected option as per the selection order in jquery.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and let me know if this is not according to your requirement...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .show_div{
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: lightyellow;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
</style>

<input type="checkbox" class="haircls" name="skin_concern[]" value="Acne" />&nbsp;Acne<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="haircls" name="skin_concern[]" value="Dark circles under eyes" />&nbsp;Dark circles under eyes<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="haircls" name="skin_concern[]" value="Dry skin" />&nbsp;Dry skin<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="haircls" name="skin_concern[]" value="Oily skin" />&nbsp;Oily skin<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="haircls" name="skin_concern[]" value="Skin color" />&nbsp;Skin color<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="haircls" name="skin_concern[]" value="Skin tone evenness" />&nbsp;Skin tone evenness<br />


<script type="text/javascript">
$('.haircls').change(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    document.getElementById('show_div_ID').innerHTML += '<span style="float:left;width:100%;">'+ this.value +'</span>';
  } else {
    $("#show_div_ID span:contains('"+this.value+"')").remove();
  }
});
</script>


<div class="show_div" id="show_div_ID"></div>
```